# .NET RegEx for substitution of language code in URL

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I change the below regular expression in C# function in order to get the result as shown below? Can I just modify the RegEx pattern instead of C# code as the total number of language codes are fixed? Thanks.

**C# function:**

```
public static string GetSubdomain(string url)
{
    string pat = @"^https://www\.(.*?)/(english|german|italian)/.*$";
    string rep = @"http://$2.$1/";
    return Regex.Replace(url, pat, rep);
}
```

**Result:**

```
http://www.example.org/english/  => http://en.example.org/
http://www.example.org/german/   => http://de.example.org/
http://www.example.org/italian/  => http://it.example.org/
```

Comment: You have to write some code: there's no way how can one produce `de` from `german`

Comment: Yes, if the first 2 characters can use to produce the country code, I can write a single regular expression without the need of mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a dictionary of language names and codes and use the following solution:

```
var dct = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "english", "en"},
    { "german", "de"},
    { "italian", "it" }
};
//var url = "http://www.example.org/english/"; // http://en.example.org/
var url = "https://www.example.org/german/"; // https://de.example.org/
string pat = @"(?i)^(https?://)www\.(.*?)/(english|german|italian)/.*$";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(url, pat, m => {
        var val = "";   
        return dct.TryGetValue(m.Groups[3].Value, out val) ?
          $"{m.Groups[1].Value}{dct[m.Groups[3].Value]}.{m.Groups[2].Value}/" :
          $"{m.Groups[1].Value}{m.Groups[3].Value}.{m.Groups[2].Value}/";
      }
    )
);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/JGbXoW).

The pattern matches

- `(?i)` - makes the regex case insensitive
- `^` - start of string
- `(https?://)` - Group 1: a `http://` or `https://`
- `www\.` - a `www.` (wrap with `(?:...)?` to match it optionally)
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `/` - a `/`
- `(english|german|italian)` - Group 3: any of the 3 alternatives
- `/` - a `/`
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `$` - end of string.

Upon matching, `dct.TryGetValue(m.Groups[3].Value, out val) ?` checks if the Group 3 value can be mapped to a language code, and if yes, `dct[m.Groups[3].Value]` is used in the replacement. Else, the `m.Groups[3].Value` is used as is.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a map, from that you can derive the regex.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> LangMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "english", "en" },
    { "german", "de" },
    { "italian", "it" }
};

private static readonly string LangString = string.Join("|", LangMap.Keys.Select(x => x).ToArray());
private static readonly Regex LangPattern = new Regex($@"(?<=https://www\.(.*?)/)({LangString})(?=/.*$)");

public static string GetSubdomain(string url)
{
    var match = LangPattern.Match(url);
    return $"http://{LangMap[match.Groups[2].Value]}.{match.Groups[1].Value}/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **general case**, I doubt if *regular expression* is of much use; we should *detect the culture* first (assuming you stick to **ISO 3166**):

```
private static CultureInfo CultureFormAddress(string address) {
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address))
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

  Uri uri = new Uri(address);
  var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);

  foreach (string segment in uri.Segments) {
    CultureInfo result = cultures
      .FirstOrDefault(culture => string.Equals(culture.EnglishName,
         segment.Trim('/'), 
         StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    if (result != null)
      return result;
  }

  return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
}
```

and only then transform the uri:

```
public static string GetSubdomain(string address) {
  CultureInfo culture = CultureFormAddress(address);

  if (culture == CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    return address;

  Uri uri = new Uri(address);

  return string.Concat(
    $"{uri.Scheme}://{culture.Name}.",
      uri.Host.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
        ? uri.Host.Substring("www.".Length) 
        : uri.Host,
      "/",
      string.Join("/", uri.LocalPath
        .Split('/')
        .SkipWhile(item => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        .Skip(1))
      );
}
```

For instance (let's provide an "unknown" culture - Russian and scheme - Ftp. and let's add local path - "bla-bla-bla"):

```
// ftp://ru.example.org/bla-bla-bla
GetSubdomain("ftp://www.example.org/russian/bla-bla-bla");
```

Other tests:

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "http://www.example.org/english/",
    "http://www.example.org/german/",
    "http://www.example.org/italian/" };

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-35} => {GetSubdomain(test)}")));
```

Outcome:

```
http://www.example.org/english/     => http://en.example.org/
http://www.example.org/german/      => http://de.example.org/
http://www.example.org/italian/     => http://it.example.org/
```